# Powershell Start-Process the filename or extension is too long

Tags: powershell, start-process

I've a error message while using credentials in start-process with a encrypted password file. In my oppinion the start-process argument credentials cannot handle the length of the encrypted password file. I tested the code with a convertion of the plain password into a secure string and use the secure string in start-process this will work. But when I using the encrypting pw file following error message appear.

start-process: this command cannot be run due to the error ; the filename or extension is too long

Invoke-Command use the encrypted pw file without problems. I Think the lenght of the variable is to long for the argument deklaration of start-process. The lenght of the content is 324 character.
Have anybody an idear?

```
$hostname = $env:computername
$pw_file_individual = 'c:\Scripts\secure_password_' + $hostname + '.txt'
$PW_File = Get-Content $pw_file_individual
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString $PW_File -AsPlainText -Force
$username = "contoso\account"
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ($username, $password)
$scriptfile = "C:\Skripte\test.ps1"

Start-process powershell.exe -credential $creds -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList '-executionpolicy bypass', '-file', $scriptfile -WorkingDirectory c:\windows\system32
```

Comment: How did you manage to set a 324 character password for a domain account in the first place?

Comment: The PW is already the encrypted password witch is read in. First of all the ad password will be encrypted with a separat script.

Comment: If the password on file is already encrypted then you don't want to use `-AsPlainText`

Comment: I've tryed $password = ConvertTo-SecureString $PW_File without -AsPlainText and now it works fine, thank u